# "use of unresolved identifier" SWIFT

Tags: swift

The error

> use of unresolved identifier 'slider'

comes where it says

> var sliderValue=slider.value

What's the problem??

```
 import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBAction func colorChanger(sender: UISlider) {
            // creates variable to hold new color
            var newBackgroundColor : UIColor

            // creates variable holding the value from slider
            var sliderValue = slider.value

            // changes the newBackgroundColor variable to new color values.
            newBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: sliderValue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

            // changes the background color
            self.view.backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor    }
```

Comment: Try `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(sender.value)....`

Comment: ... or `@IBAction func colorChanger(slider: UISlider)`

Comment: @vadian changing the sender name parameter to slider it is not a good idea.

Comment: @LeoDabus Why? The documentation says *By default, the first parameter omits its external name* that means `sender` represents the local name and local names are used only in the scope of the function. It's like closure declarations providing only the type or the parameter names in the header Objective-C files which can differ from the implementation. I'm using it quite often to have more descriptive names.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work. I cant think about a better descriptive name than sender.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a `slider` property defined in your code as far as I (or Swift ;-)) can see.

Instead you have a parameter called `sender` in your method which is a `UISlider` so try using that instead.

```
var sliderValue = sender.value
```

or

rename `sender` to `slider`

So here's one way of doing it (with some help from @leo-dabus). I took the liberty of cleaning up you code a little too, sorry :-)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func colorChanger(sender: UISlider) {
    // creates variable holding the value from slider
    let sliderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)

    // changes the newBackgroundColor variable to new color values.
    let newBackgroundColor = UIColor(hue: sliderValue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

    // changes the background color
    view.backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor    
}
```

Comment: UISlider value property returns a Float https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/value. UIColor initialiser requires a CGFloat

Comment: You're right @LeoDabus. I wasn't in front of Xcode so I took a guess. Thanks. I've changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for your question

First hook up the slider

```
@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
```

Then set minimum,maximum and current value whatever you want in storyboard or xib or programmatically

```
let sliderValue = Int(slider.value)
print("Slider value is now - \(sliderValue)")
```

Output

```
Slider value is now - 6
```